# Optimisation using Golden Search Method with Matlab

Tags: matlab

```
% Power output
power_output = MF_t.*difference.*e;

% POWER OUTPUT OPTIMIZATION USING - GOLDEN SEARCH METHOD 
x_lower = 0.2;
x_upper = 1.4;
h = (x_upper - x_lower);
r = (sqrt(5) - 1)*0.5;
x2 = x_lower + (1+r)*h;
x3 = x_upper - (1+r)*h;

tol = 0.05;
count = 1;

while h>-tol
    f2 = -power_output(x2)
    f3 = -power_output(x3)
    if f3<f2
        x_lower = x2;
        x_upper = x_upper;
        h = (x_upper - x_lower);
        x2 = x3;
        x3 = x_upper - (1-r)*h;
    elseif f2<f3
        x_lower = x_lower;
        x_upper = x3;
        h = (x_upper - x_lower);
        x3 = x2;
        x2 = x_lower + (1-r)*h;
    else
        x_lower = x2;
        x_upper = x3;
        h = (x_upper - x_lower);
        x2 = x_lower + (1+r)*h;
        x3 = x_upper - (1+r)*h;  
    end
    interval = x_upper - x_lower;
    count = count + 1
    if count > 100
        break
    end
end

answer = (x_upper + x_lower)/2
value = fanswer
```

Im trying to run this code, it's telling me that there is an error as my arrays f2 and f3 as "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values". I'm wondering would anyone know if taking the absolute values of my arrays will make my optimisation incorrect

Comment: We can't run your code, which makes diagnosis difficult...

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite informative in this case. You are trying to access the `x2`th element of `f2`. A quick calculation shows that on the first iteration `x2 = 2.14`. It is not possible to take the 2.14th element of `f2` because this is is not an integer, and taking the absolute value will not help.

`x2` is not an index, it is a value. On each iteration, the Golden Ratio search requires you to actually evaluate `power_output` with whatever variable set to `x2`. So, it looks like you need to do this calculation `power_output = MF_t.*difference.*e` with `x=x2`.

Comment: how would i get the function to do this calculation for the last sentence you mentioned

Comment: Dunno. You tell me. You are trying to find a value of `x` that gives the smallest (largest?) `power_output`. So, `power_output` must be a function of `x` and you must be able to calculate `power_output` for a given value of `x`.

Comment: i believe my issue is with power_output itself as x is not in the equation

Comment: power_out produces an array of 10 values

Comment: `x` is possibly just the name for the variable that your textbook used. You need to think what it is you are trying to minimise. So, for example, you may be trying to find the engine size that maximises the power_output, in which case x is the engine size. You have considered a range of `MF_t`, `difference` or `e` to get your 10 values (I don't know which one as you haven't posted that code) - perhaps x is one of those?

Comment: im realising as there were many more steps to power_output that i was supposed to code such that the end product would allow me to evaluate at such x values. turns out is a deeper rooted issue

Comment: Oh dear! Good luck! :)